# Matlab converting cell array to numeric matrix for svmtrain

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, svm

I have a cell array (Name it x) as follow:

1. The first element is a 1x1 struct element. (Name it apple)
2. Inside the struct element, there are 5 fields. (Name it a, b, c, d, e)
3. Inside the fields (a), it is a 1x1 struct element.
4. Inside the 1x1 struct element for a, there are 4 fields. (Name it w, x, y, z)
5. Inside each fields, there are another 6 fields. (Name it aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff)
6. Lastly, inside all of the 6 fields, those are the values I would like to retrieve.

aa, bb, cc are Strings; while dd ee ff are doubles.

So in order to access the values of aa, I would need to do something like this:

```
myValue = apple{1}.a{1}.w.aa.value;
```

In total, I have about 50+ values (50+ features) to be acquired to be used in my svmtrain. If I obtain each value individually (myValue1, myValue2, ... , myValue50) and convert them to numeric matix, it could work but it is a very long and untidy code.

Is there any way for me to convert directly the entire cell array (x) into the numeric matrix, taking the entire cell array as only **one** features, instead of 50+ lines of features as stated above?

Comment: `apple{1}.a{1}.w.aa.value;` wow. Thats maybe not the best way of storing variables in MATLAB.

Comment: Hi Ander, I didn't do the storing myself. The entire thing was actually returned from an API in that form.. So I was just wondering is there any way to fix it..